# React Native, navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to creat cart icon in my header and access it through navigation but it's showing a error

`navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate("Cart")', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)`

can someone tell me whats going on? below is my code

```
  <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={(navigation) => {
          return {
            headerTitle: () => <Header name="Shop" />,
            headerRight: () => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="cart"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Cart")}
                color="#DAA520"
                size={25}
              />
  <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a small fix here
change

```
options={(navigation) => {
```

to

```
options={({navigation}) => {
```

You get multiple properties here and you need to get only navigation.

Comment: that's silly error I forget to add {}, stupid I'm

Comment: Happens to everyone :)